# GroupBy operator for Kotlin Flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I am trying to switch from RxJava to Kotlin Flow. Flow is really impressive. But Is there any operator similar to RxJava's "GroupBy" in kotlin Flow right now?

Comment: There isn't one right now, so you'll have to write one.

Comment: I just attempted writing one and it seems counter-intuitive. Keeping in mind that Flows are cold and sequential, what do you want this `groupBy` function to return? How do you want back-pressure to be handled between the groups?

Answer (score 18):

As of Kotlin Coroutines 1.3, the standard library doesn't seem to provide this operator. However, since the design of `Flow` is such that all operators are extension functions, there is no fundamental distinction between the standard library providing it and you writing your own.

With that in mind, here are some of my ideas on how to approach it.

#### 1. Collect Each Group to a List

If you just need a list of all items for each key, use this simple implementation that emits pairs of `(K, List<T>)`:

```
fun <T, K> Flow<T>.groupToList(getKey: (T) -> K): Flow<Pair<K, List<T>>> = flow {
    val storage = mutableMapOf<K, MutableList<T>>()
    collect { t -> storage.getOrPut(getKey(t)) { mutableListOf() } += t }
    storage.forEach { (k, ts) -> emit(k to ts) }
}
```

For this example:

```
suspend fun main() {
    val input = 1..10
    input.asFlow()
            .groupToList { it % 2 }
            .collect { println(it) }
}
```

it prints

```
(1, [1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
(0, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
```

#### 2.a Emit a Flow for Each Group

If you need the full RxJava semantics where you transform the input flow into many output flows (one per distinct key), things get more involved.

Whenever you see a new key in the input, you must emit a new inner flow to the downstream and then, asynchronously, keep pushing more data into it whenever you encounter the same key again.

Here's an implementation that does this:

```
fun <T, K> Flow<T>.groupBy(getKey: (T) -> K): Flow<Pair<K, Flow<T>>> = flow {
    val storage = mutableMapOf<K, SendChannel<T>>()
    try {
        collect { t ->
            val key = getKey(t)
            storage.getOrPut(key) {
                Channel<T>(32).also { emit(key to it.consumeAsFlow()) }
            }.send(t)
        }
    } finally {
        storage.values.forEach { chan -> chan.close() }
    }
}
```

It sets up a `Channel` for each key and exposes the channel to the downstream as a flow.

#### 2.b Concurrently Collect and Reduce Grouped Flows

Since `groupBy` keeps emitting the data to the inner flows after emitting the flows themselves to the downstream, you have to be very careful with how you collect them.

You must collect all the inner flows concurrently, with no upper limit on the level of concurrency. Otherwise the channels of the flows that are queued for later collection will eventually block the sender and you'll end up with a deadlock.

Here is a function that does this properly:

```
fun <T, K, R> Flow<Pair<K, Flow<T>>>.reducePerKey(
        reduce: suspend Flow<T>.() -> R
): Flow<Pair<K, R>> = flow {
    coroutineScope {
        this@reducePerKey
                .map { (key, flow) -> key to async { flow.reduce() } }
                .toList()
                .forEach { (key, deferred) -> emit(key to deferred.await()) }
    }
}
```

The `map` stage launches a coroutine for each inner flow it receives. The coroutine reduces it to the final result.

`toList()` is a terminal operation that collects the entire upstream flow, launching all the `async` coroutines in the process. The coroutines start consuming the inner flows even while we're still collecting the main flow. This is essential to prevent a deadlock.

Finally, after all the coroutines have been launched, we start a `forEach` loop that waits for and emits the final results as they become available.

You can implement almost the same behavior in terms of `flatMapMerge`:

```
fun <T, K, R> Flow<Pair<K, Flow<T>>>.reducePerKey(
        reduce: suspend Flow<T>.() -> R
): Flow<Pair<K, R>> = flatMapMerge(Int.MAX_VALUE) { (key, flow) ->
    flow { emit(key to flow.reduce()) }
}
```

The difference is in the ordering: whereas the first implementation respects the order of appearance of keys in the input, this one doesn't. Both perform similarly.

#### 3. Example

This example groups and sums 40 million integers:

```
suspend fun main() {
    val input = 1..40_000_000
    input.asFlow()
            .groupBy { it % 100 }
            .reducePerKey { sum { it.toLong() } }
            .collect { println(it) }
}

suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.sum(toLong: suspend (T) -> Long): Long {
    var sum = 0L
    collect { sum += toLong(it) }
    return sum
}
```

I can successfully run this with `-Xmx64m`. On my 4-core laptop I'm getting about 4 million items per second.

It is simple to redefine the first solution in terms of the new one like this:

```
fun <T, K> Flow<T>.groupToList(getKey: (T) -> K): Flow<Pair<K, List<T>>> =
        groupBy(getKey).reducePerKey { toList() }
```

Comment: Can't `fold` operator be used for the same purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet but you can have a look at this library https://github.com/akarnokd/kotlin-flow-extensions .

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I was able to achieve this `non-blocking` by using `Flux.groupBy`.
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#groupBy-java.util.function.Function-

I did this in the process of converting the results obtained with `Flux` to `Flow`.
This may be an inappropriate answer for the situation in question, but I share it as an example.